# Deleting/Removing label widget on the window tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have come up with a simple program that will Load Image to the window frame by clicking a button and also remove an existing one.

**Problem**: when I use the remove_image command it only removes the existing image leaving the label that holds it behind rather than removing the label with the image instead. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong with my this code. please and thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Label
import os
import sys
root = Tk()
root.title("Mole Tester")
root.geometry("800x500")
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

optionframe = Frame (root, width=800, height=450, bg="light gray", 
                     relief=SUNKEN)
optionframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)


load = Label(optionframe, padx=140, pady=125, bg="white", font=('Times new 
             roman', 10, 'bold'), text="Import Image", relief=RAISED).place (x=10, y=10)


#Image Remove    
def clear_label_image():
    brand_preview.image = None    
    imagelabel.destroy() 

#Image Load
def openfile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open')
    return filename

def load_img():
    x = openfile()
    img = Image.open(x)
    img = img.resize((360, 270), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    imagelabel = Label(optionframe, width=360, height=270, image=img, 
                       relief=RAISED).place(x=10, y=10)
    imagelabel.pack()


    loadbutton = Button(optionframe, padx=18, pady=1, bd=8, fg="black",
                        font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Load Image", bg="gray", 
                        command=load_img).place(x=18, y=320)
    removebutton = Button(optionframe, padx=30, pady=1, bd=8, fg="black", 
                          font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Remove", bg="gray",
                          command=clear_label_image).place(x=18, y=365)
```

Comment: where do you use an remove_image command? Why don't you simply use pack_forget(widget) and widget.destroy(); where is your application main loop?

Comment: `imagelabel` is a local variable. Are you aware of the distinction between local variables and global variables?

Comment: oh im sorry for not including the app main loop. i used  the command <clear_image_label> and have tried some codes base on what ive understand while googling.

Comment: i have no idea about this local and global variable, i have only tried this codes based from the video tutorials. How do i suppose to identify when im going to use a  global or local variable?. thanks.

Comment: thanks I'll try reading  more about variable to help me with this problem.

Comment: i have use this code <brand_preview.image = None > to remove the image and <imagelabel.destroy()> to remove the label but unfortunately only the image can be successfully remove leaving the label behind.